# How can I make hybrid ircd flood protection more relaxed or disable it entirely?

Tags: ircd-hybrid

I'm running a server on an internal network and connect a few bots to it and sometimes the bots will spit out a lot of lines. I've made the bots reconnect after being kicked but that's merely treating the symptoms.

How can I make the flood protection more relaxed/disable it? My install is pretty much out of the box by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTFM it turns out.

in the `general` block in `/etc/ircd/ircd.conf` set

```
/* no oper flood: increase flood limits for opers. */
no_oper_flood = yes;

/* true no oper flood: completely eliminate flood limits for opers
     * and for clients with can_flood = yes in their auth {} blocks
 */
true_no_oper_flood = yes;
```

And an `auth` block as:

```
auth {
        user = "*@*";
        class = "users";

        /* restricted: stop the client sending mode changes */
        #restricted = yes;

        /* have ident: require the user has identd to connect (OLD I: + flag) */
        have_ident = no;

        can_flood = yes;
    };
```

Needless to say don't do that on any publicly accessible server.